# Data string manipulation in excel

Tags: excel, dataset, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a custom dropdown in excel 2013.  It is populated by a dataset saved on a different sheet within the same workbook.
Each value is ended with an ID.
I want to populate the a-joining column with the "R001" ID value so it has it's own column like so:

```
ReportName          ReportID
"blahblah R1"       R1
"blahblah E1"       E1
```

So basically, a user selects a choice from the ReportName Column with the dropdown, and the ReportID column will auto populate with the corresponding ID.  I've tried modifying my dataset further to accommodate, without luck.

I've also played around with IF statements, but the approach I have tried is extremely limited:

```
=IF(RIGHT(B3,2)<>"","R1","")
```

Can anyone please advise?

Report Name is B1, under that, is the dropdown B2 (which pulls it's content from Sheet2 in the workbook)
ReportID is C1, under that (C2), will be the corresponding ReportID, which I can also pull from Sheet2 in the workbook

I need to lock C2, C3, C4 etc... so the user cannot edit, and the number corresponds to the ID of the value in B2. The dropdown which is copy and pasted from B2 as many times as required to B3, B4 (depending on users needs) Will NOT bee in a logical order, so the ReportID logic has to "check" the value in ReportName - to ensure it matches correctly.

Comment: Why don't you use `vlookup` function in excel

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, can you elaborate?

Comment: Type VLOOKUP in excel help, it will show you how to use it. If you need a live demo go here http://www.timeatlas.com/5_minute_tips/general/learning_vlookup_in_excel#.UpOBmdLdc2Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really familiar with excel 2013, but the below works for 2010. If that doesn't work, it should at least be close.

Is your report name always the same length? If so, you could use something like:

```
=if(b2="","",right(b2,2))
```

If id length changes sometimes, but there is always a space between the name and the report id, you could use:

```
=if(b2="","",trim(right(b2,len(b2)-find(" ",b2)))
```

Then to lock the column, select the columns you don't want to be locked, go to format cells, unclick the locked check box in the protection tab, and lock the worksheet.

Comment: Was able to modify this and get something working.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `ReportName` in `ColumnA1`(which is a dropdown) and want to populate `ReportID`in `ColumnB1` (once dropdown value is selected). Also lets assume that you have the above given data in `ColumnC1` to `ColumnD2`. Use the following formula in`ColumnB1`

```
=VLOOKUP($A$1,$D$1:$E$6,2,0)
```

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer with more details.  The VLOOKUP didn't work, I'm not sure it's what I need.

Comment: Quite difficult to understand even thou you have given your best to explain. You can email your sheet if you so prefer so that I can solve it for you (refer my profile)

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll get to this asap.